# Contar el numero de elementos de un array en C#

Tags: c#

Tendré un array como el siguiente:

```
string[] arr1 = { "one", "two", "three" };
```

Como podría hacer para contar el numer total de elementos que se encuentra en mi array. Intente añadiendole `Count` pero  me devuelve:

```
El nombre 'arr1.Count' no existe en el contexto actual.
```

Osea que no existe tal método hay alguna manera sencilla o aunque sea usando bucles para contar el numero de elementos de un array en C#?

Comment: El error que te lanza es porque no existe una variable *arr2*

Comment: has probado poniendo `array count` en google? era necesario una pregunta?

Comment: Si tal vez tenga que buscar mejor.......

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usa [Length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx):

> arr1.Length

Ejemplo:

```
string[] arr1 = { "one", "two", "three" };
Console.WriteLine("Cantidad de elementos en el arreglo: " + arr1.Length);
// Resultado: Cantidad de elementos en el arreglo: 3
```

Answer (score 4):

Ampliando tus necesidades, si tienes un array de una dimension con

```
array.GetLength(0)
```

recuperas la longitud de esta unica y primera dimension, si tienes de dos dimensiones con

```
array.GetLength(1)
```

recuperas la longitud de la segunda dimension... y asi con todas las dimensiones que puedas tener.

Answer (score 1):

Los arrays no tienen una propiedad `Count`. Tienes que usar el método [Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/es-es/library/bb338038(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
arr1.Count();
```

O como bien dice el amigo Mauricio Arias, usar la propiedad `Length`. De hecho, yo te recomendaría usar esta ultima y aceptar su respuesta.